# jQuery Dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm going to create a quick search on my contents;

i have following HTML code :

```
<ul id='dynamic'>
 <li data-c='a'></li>
 <li data-c='b'></li>
 <li data-c='c'></li>
</ul>
```

to my search target, and the `#dynamic` id could change to any thing;

```
$.post("ajax.php", { sort:$(this).val() }).done(function(data) {
$("#dynamic").html(data);
});
```

when im try to get the "`<li>`" element using $.each(), the replaced elements return false;
actually i should something like $.live(each,function(){}); but there is nothing like this function.

`$.post` request is in another function and im trying to get `li` elements by $.each;
example :

```
$("li").each(function(){

// do stuff.

});
```

when i changing content via ajax the code above not working.
what should i do?
EDIT : ( this part of my code will not work , If `#myElm`'s child remove or replace with anything else. _

```
$("#dynamic").find("li").each(function(){
// do stuff
});
```

" sorry for poor eng "

Comment: An `.each()` loop like `$("li").each(...` will loop over whatever li elements exist at the time the loop runs, regardless of whether the elements were created dynamically. I don't know what you mean by "the replaced elements return false", but please show more of the code that doesn't work and explain where it is called from (and when).

Comment: do you want a click event handler also which is the jQuery version used

Comment: i think new elements " `li` " is out of loop and `each` is not working

Comment: @nnnnnn , i just updated my question , take a look

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Answer (score 0):

if jQuery > 1.7 is used then

```
$('#dynamic').on('click', 'li', function(){
    alert('clicked' + $(this).text())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

$.post make asynchronous ajax call to the specific url
I think you are trying to do each on the content that are not yet loaded .
Use synchronous request or do your stuff in done function

```
$.post("ajax.php", { sort:$(this).val() }).done(function(data) { // asynchronous request  
$("#dynamic").html(data);
});

$("li").each(function(){ // but  $("#dynamic") is not yet updated by ajax due to asynchronous request 

// do stuff.

});
```

Change your code to

```
$.post("ajax.php", { sort:$(this).val() }).done(function(data) {
    $("#dynamic").html(data);

    $("li").each(function(){ //on updation of  $("#dynamic") by asynchronous request 

    // do stuff.

    });
    });
```

Or use sync request by $.ajax

```
    $.ajax({url:"ajax.php", data:{ sort:$(this).val() },async:false,type:"post",
    success:function(){
    $("#dynamic").html(data);
      }});

$("li").each(function(){ //on updation of  $("#dynamic") by sync request 

        // do stuff.

        });
```

**async:false** prevent from asynchronous request

Comment: these are two different functions i using , `$("li").each()` run after the request .